# IE: Toolbar vs Explorer Bar

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

I created an IE Toolbar via C#.  When I go to IE 8, I see my creation listed under
View > Toolbars as I expected.  But it also appears under View > Explorer Bars
I don't think this is a good thing.  The Google Toolbar, for example, appears only under Toolbars.  Thanks for whatever help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your object only in the places that you want it to appear.  I'm willing to bet that you built your toolbar off someone else's demo, so you'll need to adjust the demo to match your goals.

http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/dotnetbandobjects.asp

Comment: Thank you!  Btw, I hope you aren't speaking of building on someone's demo as a bad thing.
Thanks again!